Unsupported converter, only named functions, types and lambdas are currently supported
Using the complicated example as here https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attrs.converters.default_if_none, I get the mypy error: Unsupported converter, only named functions, types and lambdas are currently supported
def complicated(value, self_, field):
    return int(value) * self_.factor + field.metadata["offset"]
@define
class C:
    factor = 5  # not an *attrs* field
    x = field(
        metadata={"offset": 200},
        converter=attrs.Converter(
            complicated,
            takes_self=True, takes_field=True
    ))
C("42")
C(x=410)


mypy just doesn't support that. There's a lot of perfectly safe, valid, fine code that mypy doesn't support. You can tell mypy to ignore it with a # type: ignore comment, or you can stop writing your code like that.
There isn't really a way to get the same converter behavior without attrs.Converter. You could hardcode the offset, but if you try to hardcode factor, your converter will behave differently if you reassign an instance's factor and then try to reassign x. You'd probably be stuck ditching attrs and writing a custom __init__ and a custom @property.

Strictly speaking, it's the attrs plugin for mypy that doesn't support it. (Not sure why; I assume field has to statically determine the return type of the converter in order to provide a static type for x, but it am I wrong in assuming that Converter should be able to pull that from its first argument? Maybe it's possible, but more complicated than the plugin has been made to handle yet.)

My class is frozen so I cannot do it with init. I have an amount property that I need to adjust its precision based on another property. A classic Money class implementation with an amount and a Currency
